# AES s-box representation

Tags: aes, s-boxes

I have seen in various papers like in [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/085.pdf) one page 4, that the AES s-box equation is:

$S=A \circ φ^{-1}(φ(x)^{254})$ where $φ$ is the isomorphism from $\mathbb{F}_2^{8}$ to $\mathbb{F}_{2^{8}}$ with its basis and the reduction polynomial and $A$ is the affine transformation defined in AES.

I am kind of new to this area, but what I would say is that $φ(x)^{254}$ is the inverse of $φ(x)$ since their multiplication generates the $φ(x)^{255}$. The degree with the reduction polynomial is 255 right? (Since it's irreducible, but I am not sure if we should include zero as well)

So, what I would expect is:

$S=A \circ φ(x)^{254}$

How did the first equation come up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tricky point is that $\mathbb{F}_2^8$ is not a field; it is a degree-8 vector space. Multiplications are not defined on vector spaces. However, the $A$ transform is defined only on the vector space, not on the field (it is "affine" only when considering its source/destination space as a vector space).

The $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ operations are thus "type conversions". If you think of it in terms of implementations, they are akin to type casts: if $x$ is a vector, then $\phi(x)$ is the same sequence of bits, but interpreted as a field element. So you have to apply $\phi$ (i.e. switch to field interpretation) in order to do field-related things (here, exponentiation), then $\phi^{-1}$ must be apply on the result to go back to vector space interpretation, so that a vector space affine transform ($A$) may be applied.

A possible source of confusion is the notation $\phi^{-1}$ that means "the inverse function" (i.e. the one that goes in the reverse direction), but *not* "the inverse of the value". The same term ("inverse") and the same notation (exponentiation with $-1$) are used for two very different things.

Also, $z^{254}$ indeed computes the inverse of $z$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^8}$, but it also returns 0 when the source value is 0, which is what we want in AES, while the inverse of 0 is nominally not defined. Hence the use of exponentiation in the formula, instead of inversion.